# firebase Sign in with email and password not working with await function vuejs

Tags: firebase, vue.js

```
 async signIn() {
   try {   
           let userCredential= await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
           console.log("user value is",userCredential)
           this.$router.replace({name:'Sidebar'})      
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Invalid user", err);
      }
    },
  },
};
```

When I use login without the `await` function it logs in, even on wrong credentials, and if I use the await function nothing happens and also it shows no errors.

When using the `await` function even on wrong credentials it's not showing an error, and also on correct credentials, it's not showing `console.log` value. What am I doing wrong here? why is it not checking DB for email and password!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. The form was not submitting the correct value at submission. Had to render the value outside the form and pass the values normally without form.

Answer (score 0):

You should dont use try catch here, make it simple like this. Beside you should not post information about firebase. It is sensitive infor.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
   .then(function(firebaseUser) {
       // Success 
       console.log("user value is", firebaseUser)
       this.$router.replace({name:'Sidebar'})
   })
  .catch(function(error) {
       // Error Handling
       console.log("Invalid user", error);
  });
```

Comment: I tried that simple way too but still, it's not working, and thanks, I removed the firebase code.It shows no errors too so I really don't understand what is the problem.